# Dynamic controls in an UpdatePanel not always raises asynchronously

Tags: c#, dynamic, asynchronous, updatepanel

I try to create a dynamic table with some textboxes depending on a object List.
Then I add it in an Panel contained in UpdatePanel.

Everything works great, except that some times, the postback is async, and some times, all the page reloads. There is no rule, some times it will work twice before being full postback, and some times more. Can't find a logic with this behaviour.

Here is a piece of my aspx code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="udpTableDechets" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlTableDechets" runat="server" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Here is a piece of my code behind:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    generateTableDechets();
    base.OnLoad(e);
}

private void generateTableDechets()
{
    Table tbl = new Table { ID = "dechets", ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static };

    TableRow trDec = new TableRow();
    tbl.Controls.Add(trDec);

    TableCell tdDecReel = new TableCell();
    trDec.Controls.Add(tdDecReel);
    TextBox txtDechet = new TextBox { ID = string.Concat("txtDechet_", product.Nom), ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static, AutoPostBack = true };
    txtDechet.TextChanged+=new EventHandler(txtDechet_TextChanged);
    tdDecReel.Controls.Add(txtDechet);

    pnlTableDechets.Controls.Add(tbl);
}

protected void txtDechet_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get the value, and update the object containing values
    // Then update labels in table thanks to another method
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

Actually, I tried the same in static, and I have exactly the same behaviour.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txt_TextChanged" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Is it normal for you ? Is it a known bug ? Have I forgive something ? 
How can I do to be sure every textChanged request will execute asynchronously.
Thank you in advance for your answers

**Update 2**

The problem seems to occur when I press Enter key or when I hilight the textbox content to replace it.

**Solution**

I finally did it thanks to the IPostBackEventHandler Interface ([see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153112.aspx)).

I manage the event manually, and catch it in the RaisePostBackEvent() method. So here, thanks to the control ID passed in parameter, I can do my stuff.

Thank you for your answers

Comment: where you are updating your update panel? as it is conditional

Comment: I did an Update(), but controls are within the updatePanel, so no need to call the Update method.

Answer (score 0):

It is a comman issue while creating a website that contain dynamic controls.
If you want to fire event each time you should call code behind from javascript.
Since javascript is executed each time.

ex.

```
function SaveClick() {
            Page.GetPostBackEventReference(objBtnSave);
            __doPostBack("objBtnSave", "OnClick");
        }
```

May be this will resolve your problem.

Comment: problem is not with firing the events, it always fires. But some time asynchronously, some time synchronously

Comment: You put me on the way with the GetPostBackEventReference. I edit my question to put the answer. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

In static, I made it work adding the ChildrenAsTriggers="true" Property, or specifying an AsyncPostBackTrigger on each dynamic control with the TextChanged event.

But this does not work with my dynamic code.